# Can not insert data into two tables spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Im using Spring mvc and facing the problem about inserting data into two tables, my target is inserting data into 2 tables from 1 jsp (1 form)
I have two 2 tables:

```
1.Cars
  Id
  Name
  CityId(FK) 

2.City
  Id
  Name
```

this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateCar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getCreateCarPage(ModelMap model) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        Car myCar = new Car();
        City city = new City();

        myCar.setCity(city);

        model.addAttribute("city", city);
        model.addAttribute("createCar", myCar);
    }       
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("testForm");
}
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateCar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setCreateCarPage(ModelMap model,
                                     @ModelAttribute("createCar") Car createCar) throws SQLException, Exception {

    try {

        carService.createCar(createCar);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ModelAndView("successProcess");
}
```

}

JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="createCar" method="POST" commandName="createCar" action="/CreateCar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset style="width:300px">          
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">                              
    <tr>            
        <td>
            <label>Name of car</label>
            <form:input path="name" id="name"/>
        </td>       

        <td>
            <label>Name of city</label>
            <form:input path="city.name" />
        </td>                   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Inser New" style="width:100px;" /></td>          
    </tr>   
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

With above source, it just insert name of car success but can not insert name of city

Log massages:

```
SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'city_id' cannot be null
```

How can I fix this problem ? thank so much !

Comment: your id is auto generated i suppose , please change that in the entity class. as city_id is your primary key i feel and it cannot be empty

Comment: @RahulSingh: I bookmarked your commend, and what's else guys ?

Comment: what else ? means u change that and it should work

Comment: you get this message because your form send a null city object when you write  <form:input path="city.name" /> it's like your set a value in a  Null.name field

Comment: Yes I see city.name is null, but how to fix this ?

Comment: You don't need this  `myCar.setCity(city);` and  `model.addAttribute("city", city);` as the goal is just to create a Car. And you can retrieve your city from Car model after submitting the form, then processing the insert operation.

Comment: @akuma8: yes guy, I just need to create new information of car and insert data to 2 tables, current my problem: city.name is textfield(input), not selectbox and it can not insert.. and I try your advance